# Handlebars.js beginning

Tags: handlebars.js

I am new to handlebars.js and I started to play around with it. However I am already stuck could you please explain what I am doing wrong?

This is in the head tag:

```
 <script id="header" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div> {{ headerTitle }} </div>
  Today is {{weekDay}}
 </script>
```

and this in the body:

```
<script>

      var theData = {headerTitle:"Shop Page", weekDay:"Wednesday"};  
       var theTemplateScript = $("#header").html();  
       var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile (theTemplateScript);  
       $(document).append (theTemplate (theData));

 </script>
```

The page suppose to return the following:

Shop Page
Today is Wednesday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template works, you just need to append the generated markup to an element.

```
$("body").append(theTemplate(theData));
```